# Python's pandas gives wrong weekday index for DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to take timeseries data, and count the average number of rows per weekday (Monday, Tuesday, ...). My data are like this:

```
timestamp       maxCapacity
Mon Aug  4 14:47:00 EDT 2014    6741
Mon Aug  4 14:48:01 EDT 2014    6741
```

To accomplish this, I start by indexing a dataframe by timestamp. Then I create a new column by getting the weekday from the timestamp index. However, the new column does not correctly assign weekday numbers.

Here is code for producing the problem.

```
import wget, pandas, csv
from dateutil import parser
url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbti3i8uzy82hw6/maxCapacity?dl=1'
dataFile = 'maxCapacitySample'
if not os.path.exists(dataFile):
    wget.download(url, out=dataFile)

parse = lambda x: parser.parse(x)

tdata = pandas.read_csv(dataFile,
                        parse_dates={"Datetime":['timestamp',]},
                        index_col='Datetime',
                        keep_date_col=False,
                        date_parser=parse,
                        dialect=csv.excel_tab)

tdata['weekday'] = tdata.index.weekday
print tdata.head()
```

The output

```
                       maxCapacity  weekday
Datetime
2014-08-04 14:40:00-04:00         6741        0
2014-08-04 14:47:00-04:00         6741        3
2014-08-04 14:48:01-04:00         6741        3
2014-08-04 14:49:00-04:00         6741        3
2014-08-04 14:50:00-04:00         6741        3
```

The problem here is that the same day (the 4th) is mapped to weekdays 0 and 3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version?  Seemed to work ok on 0.14.1/py2.7/Windows.  Could you show `tdata.info()`

Comment: @chrisb I was able to reproduce the OP's issue on pandas 0.14.1/py2.7/Linux.

Comment: don't use the dateutil parser at all no reason to; it has all kinds of odd things that it does

Comment: @chrisb 0.12.0/py2.7.5/os x mavericks
    `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce on 0.14.1/py2.7/osx yosemite

Comment: @Jeff Now this is interesting. I can confirm that the OP's code works just fine on Windows, exactly like what chrisb saw. And it fails on Linux, like what the OP saw. This is with pandas 0.14.1 on Python 2.7.

Comment: @Jeff The dateutil parser was the problem. I upgraded to 0.14.1, but it didn't help. Removing the dateutil code fixed the issue on 0.14.1.

Comment: dateutil has so many issues pandas barely uses it and only after trying a zillion other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a workaround via:

```
tdata['weekday'] = pandas.to_datetime(tdata.index.values).weekday
```

The resulting DataFrame is:

```
                           maxCapacity  weekday
Datetime
2014-08-04 14:40:00-04:00         6741        0
2014-08-04 14:47:00-04:00         6741        0
2014-08-04 14:48:01-04:00         6741        0
2014-08-04 14:49:00-04:00         6741        0
2014-08-04 14:50:00-04:00         6741        0
2014-08-04 14:51:00-04:00         6741        0
2014-08-04 14:52:00-04:00         6741        0
2014-08-04 14:53:00-04:00         6741        0
2014-08-04 14:54:00-04:00         6741        0
2014-08-04 14:55:00-04:00         6741        0
...                                ...      ...
2014-08-20 09:37:00-04:00         6652        2
2014-08-20 09:38:00-04:00         6654        2
2014-08-20 09:39:00-04:00         6651        2
2014-08-20 09:40:00-04:00         6642        2
2014-08-20 09:41:00-04:00         6648        2
2014-08-20 09:42:00-04:00         6654        2
2014-08-20 09:43:00-04:00         6646        2
2014-08-20 09:44:00-04:00         6659        2
2014-08-20 09:45:00-04:00         6650        2
2014-08-20 09:46:00-04:00         6655        2

[6589 rows x 2 columns]
```